# rename columns in SQL Query transpose

Tags: sql, rename, transpose

I have a SQL query than transpose rows by columns but i dont know how to rename the columns.

```
select * 
from 
    (select CustomerID, FiscalPeriod, SaleAmtLocalCurr  
     from PerfTrk.dbo.IRIS_SaleFact 
     where CountryCode = '00001' 
       and DivisionCode = 'INS' 
       and SaleAmtLocalCurr > 0 
       and datefromparts(FiscalYear, FiscalPeriod, 1) between datefromparts(2019,9, 1) and  datefromparts(2020,8, 31)) d
pivot 
    (sum(SaleAmtLocalCurr) for FiscalPeriod in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]) 
    ) piv;
```

The result is

```
CustomerID 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
```

I want to rename the columns with the names of months

Thanks

Comment: Do you want it while mentioning the pivoting values ?otherwise it would be to just give alias to each instead of `*`

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` is always an option

```
select 
    * 
from 
    (select 
            CustomerID, 
            (CASE 
                WHEN FiscalPeriod = 1 THEN 'JAN'
                WHEN FiscalPeriod = 2 THEN 'FEB'
                WHEN FiscalPeriod = 3 THEN 'MAR' 
                WHEN FiscalPeriod = 4 THEN 'APR'
                WHEN FiscalPeriod = 5 THEN 'MAY'
                WHEN FiscalPeriod = 6 THEN 'JUN'
                WHEN FiscalPeriod = 7 THEN 'JUL'
                WHEN FiscalPeriod = 8 THEN 'AUG'
                WHEN FiscalPeriod = 9 THEN 'SEP'
                WHEN FiscalPeriod = 10 THEN 'OCT'
                WHEN FiscalPeriod = 11 THEN 'NOV'
                WHEN FiscalPeriod = 12 THEN 'DEC'
            END) AS 'Month',
            SaleAmtLocalCurr  
     from 
            PerfTrk.dbo.IRIS_SaleFact 
     where 
            CountryCode = '00001' 
       and DivisionCode = 'INS' 
       and SaleAmtLocalCurr > 0 
       and datefromparts(FiscalYear, FiscalPeriod, 1) 
             between datefromparts(2019,9, 1) and  datefromparts(2020,8, 31)) d
pivot 
    (sum(SaleAmtLocalCurr) for FiscalPeriod in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]) 
    ) piv;
```